# Why doesn't StackExchange Do Something About ExpertsOverflow.com?

Tags: discussion

> *I can't find a better place to ask this question - 
>   if there is one, please suggest it and I will repost there.*

expertsoverflow.com is a blatant screen scrape of stackoverflow.com.  Everything is copied - graphics, the name (Stack Overflow), everything.  It's a blatant violation of copyright.  Why don't the Powers That Be at SO shut them down?

Comment: ... `expertsexchange.com` doesn't exist. It's a ad-filled empty website. Looks like you wanted `expertsoverflow.com`.